# Problem with Euler method when derivative divides by zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider following differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2(1+x^2)$$

For $y(0)=1$, its solution is:

$$y(x) = \frac{-1}{x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+-1}$$

A few steps of Euler method are performed:

$$
h = 1, \space x_0=0, \space y(x_0) = 1 \\
y(x_1) = y(x_0) + 1\cdot f(y(0), x_0) = 1+1\cdot [1^2\cdot (1+0^2)] = 2 = y(1) \\
y(x_2) = y(x_1) + 1\cdot f(y(1), x_1) = 2+1\cdot [2^2\cdot (1+1^2)] = 10 = y(2)
\\
y(x_3) = y(x_2) + 1\cdot f(y(2), x_2) = 10+1\cdot [10^2\cdot (1+2^2)] = 510 = y(3)
$$

The values quickly go up. Now, exact solution is way different. It's undefined for $x=0.81773$, goes high up before that value, and start from low down after the value. Why isn't this in any way reflected in results given by Euler method? It utilizes slope description provided by $y^2(1+x^2)$, shouldn't this slope description reflect the exact solution?

Comment: Step width $h=1$ is much too large; you should begin by reducing it. general remark: don't loose too much time on Euler method: it is not worth the interest. Turn to fruitful methods like Runge-Kutta.

Comment: I make my remark more precise: as you have a vertical asymptote at x=0.8... Starting at (0,1) and making a +1 step makes you cross the discontinuity of your function. So don't be astonished that something weird happens. Euler method is made to follow more or less a branch of a curve, not jump from one to another.